# Thread Synchronization for Cocos2d application

Tags: multithreading, cocoa, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

In my cocos2d game i have a some balls which must be destroyed, and there are 2 threads which are concurrent with each other, first thread add balls to the NSMutablearray, and second thread iterate through this array and calls release method for each ball,i have put every operation with array in synchronized block with @synchronized(array) but its not affect and every time in synchronized block application throws an exception __NSArrayM was mutated while being enumerated:
maybe there is other way to synchronize threads?

Comment: Can you post the actual code of the iteration/addition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're adding objects from one thread and iterating over the same array with another thread, it seems rather pointless to multithread this part of your code.

The reason is that you [can not modify an array while iterating](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/objectEnumerator) over it, regardless of whether you do it from within the same thread or multiple threads.

You will most likely get better results by using two arrays, one for each thread, and each thread perfoming the same tasks: both are adding objects, then both iterate over their half half of the objects. How you split the objects is up to you, it could be based on screen coordinates (screen split) or some other condition (ie balance number of objects processed by each thread).

Comment: i want to ask a question about cocos2d, how it handles schedules? because this problem mostly caused on iphone 4, but on iphone 3G it works fine, in game there is also a Box2d and sometimes i change this arrays on ContactListener methods,but in this methods i also put it's to synchronized block, does cocos2d use a single thread for all schedules?i'm not manually create a threads, i only suppose that if in 3g it works it seems that on 4 there are more than one thread to handle schedlues and it crashed the application